# xml Serialization and Deserialization (hide one node header)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML file and I need to deserialize it.  Without bypassing all the nodes, just deserilizing the XML file to an object.

Is it possible to hide from the result ActionGetSiteResultData or only one way 
use custom serialization/deserialization?

Classes:

```
// root
public Result Result { get; set; }
// rows
public class Result 
{
  public List<ResultData> Data { get; set; }
}
//item
public class ResultData
{
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "gen_info")]
  public GenInfo GenInfo { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "hosting")]
   public Hosting Hosting { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

```
  <Result>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Data>
          <ResultData> <--- REMOVE THIS
             <gen_info>
                <ascii-name>sadsad</ascii-name>
              </gen_info>
              <hosting/>
          </ResultData> <--- REMOVE THIS
    </Data>
  </Result>
```

Need:

```xml
<Result>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Data>
        <gen_info>
            <ascii-name>sadsad</ascii-name>
         </gen_info>
         <hosting/>
    </Data>
  </Result>
<Result>
 <Id>2</Id>
 <Data>
   <gen_info>
      <ascii-name>sadsad2</ascii-name>
    </gen_info>
    <hosting/>
  </Data>
 </Result>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do but is verbose. Try [XmlElement(ElementName = "gen_info")] on ResultData property first, if it doesn't work:

```
public class Result 
{
  [XmlIgnore]
  public List<ResultData> Data { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "gen_info")]
  public ResultData[] __XmlSerializedData{
    get{ return Data.ToArray();}
    set{ Data = new List<ResultData>(value);}
  }
}
```